# Strange bleed-through when multi-selecting controls in IDE

Tags: vb6

I don't know when this started happening - I've been using VB, every flavor, since the 3.0 release, but for at least several years now, at least since Windows 7 (then 8 now 10) I've noticed that if I try to select multiple controls on a form, the resize handles disappear.

They are there if I select only one control, but selecting either via shift, control, or lasso, it does select but you have no idea for certain until you try to move the controls en-masse if they are all selected or not because there's no visible clues in the IDE.

But that's not even the strangest part.  I can have several other full-screen apps beneath the VB6 IDE, like Chrome, Outlook, etc., and the handles outline will bleed through to the desktop wallpaper!  It's not even on the wallpaper itself because I have wallpaper that changes periodically, and it's happened whether or not it's a fixed wallpaper.  The desktop is littered with re-size handle marks for every group of controls I've done with the current running session of VB6.  The only thing that clears them is closing VB6.

I've learned to live with this fluke, but I miss the days when I could clearly see the controls I've selected and don't have a cluttered-up wallpaper.

Anyone else encountered this strange behavior and/or know of a possible solution?

Edit:  Added a screen cap of a portion of my desktop as it is now:

[image]

Comment: Are you not running it in [compatibility mode](https://s33.postimg.cc/lrxyj8fjj/vb6.png)?

Comment: I think you were on to something.  I did not realize that the shortcut was set to run in compatibility mode by default.  When I cleared that option, not only has the problem not re-appeared (yet), but the program is LIGHTNING fast.  It used to take between one and two minutes to load my 200+ form accounting system, but it loaded it in seconds flat.  The screen is still a little flaky, but much better.